# Wordpress - Customizing Breadcrumbs NavXT

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

Right now my breadcrumbs are showing up like `Home > Services > X-Ray`, but I would like them to just show up like `Home > Services`, is there a way to customize Breadcrumbs NavXT to do this this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go in /wp-content/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/class.bcn_breadcrumb_trail.php

find function display and replace it with:

```
public function display($return = false, $linked = true, $reverse = false)
{
    //Set trail order based on reverse flag
    $this->order($reverse);
    //Initilize the string which will hold the assembled trail
    $trail_str = '';
    $position = 1;
    //The main compiling loop
    foreach($this->breadcrumbs as $key => $breadcrumb)
    {
        //We do different things for the separator based on the breadcrumb order
        if($reverse)
        {
            //Add in the separator only if we are the 2nd or greater element
            if($key > 0)
            {
                $trail_str .= $this->opt['hseparator'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($key == 0  ) continue;
            //Only show the separator when necessary
            if($key < count($this->breadcrumbs) - 1)
            {
                $trail_str .= $this->opt['hseparator'];
            }
        }
        //Trim titles, if needed
        if($this->opt['blimit_title'] && $this->opt['amax_title_length'] > 0)
        {
            //Trim the breadcrumb's title
            $breadcrumb->title_trim($this->opt['amax_title_length']);
        }
        //Place in the breadcrumb's assembled elements
        $trail_str .= $breadcrumb->assemble($linked, $position);
        $position++;
    }
    //Should we return or echo the assembled trail?
    if($return)
    {
        return $trail_str;
    }
    else
    {
        //Helps track issues, please don't remove it
        $credits = "<!-- Breadcrumb NavXT " . $this::version . " -->\n";
        echo $credits . $trail_str;
    }
}
```

if you use a different version i have add this row:

```
if($key == 0  ) continue;
```